# How to make UIAlertView disappear automatically?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want to make it so that when you press a button, an alert pops up for a second or two and then disappears on its own. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer seems a little dangerous. From the docs (emphasis mine)

> A selector that identifies the method to invoke. The method should not have a significant return value and should take a **single argument** of type **id**, or no arguments.

This selector takes two arguments and the argument is a primitive not an `id`. So this appears to be working by coincidence...

A safer way that I think reads better as you call the method in the normal way but just use gcd for scheduling:

```
__weak __typeof(alertView) weakAlertView = alertView;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [weakAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
});
```

Comment: yes, if the user clicks very fast, performSelector would be sent to an alertView object that is deallocated.

Comment: Cool, I switched my code to this and it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: Actually, I get a little exclamation mark saying "__weak attribute cannot be specified on...".

Comment: Going to need to full warning... Check the log navigator

Comment: __weak attribute cannot be specified on an automatic variable when ARC is not enabled. This makes sense because I disabled ARC earlier for a specific error I was getting.

Comment: You would be much better off going back and fixing that one issue to work with ARC. You should really be using ARC as it's much safer than manual memory management, especially if you have not got much experience with manual memory management.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this after the line which shows your alert view:

```
[alertView performSelector:@selector(dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] afterDelay:2];
```